# How to hide a column using MDDataTable (kivy) in a python app

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have tried a couple of ways to hide a column, such as:

```
column_data=[("Date-Time", dp(25)),
                     ("First Name", dp(25)),
                     ("Last Name", dp(25)),
                     ("Record Number", dp(0)),....
```

or
width=[dp(25), dp(25), dp(25), dp(0)....

or
width=[(25, 25), (25, 25), (25, 25), (0,0),....

none of them have worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create two `MDDataTables`, one without the column that you want hidden, and just switch between the two to hide that column. Having said that, here is a hack that seems to work in hiding a column in the example `MDDataTable` from the `kivyMD` documentation:

```
def hide_column(self, col):
    if col < 1:
        return  # cannot hide column 0

    # change the column header
    th = self.data_tables.table_data.table_header
    num_cols = len(th.ids.header.children)
    child_index = num_cols - 1 - col
    if child_index < 0:
        return  # col number is beyond last column
    th.ids.header.children[child_index].ids.lbl.text = ""

    # change the rows
    for row in self.data_tables.row_data:
        new_row = row[:]
        new_row[col] = ""
        self.data_tables.update_row(row, new_row)
```

add this method to your `MDApp` class. In order for this method to work, you must use `[]` (rather than `()`) to define each row in the row data, since tuples (defined using `()`) are immutable.